# Cloudflare minify html and gzip

Tags: cloudflare

Hi I have a Drupal 6 site with Cloudflare as cdn. I also have gzip enabled via apache server setting.

I want to know if I can enable gzip along with Cloudflare html minify? Thanks

Comment: Yes, there's no problem if you want to enable gzip plus Cloudflare html minify

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare dynamically GZips content on supported browsers, and presents this to the end user. This works regardless of whether HTML minify is turned on or off.

Related:

- [What will Cloudflare gzip?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168396-What-will-CloudFlare-gzip-)
- [Does Cloudflare gzip resources?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168086-Does-Cloudflare-gzip-resources-)